# woocommerce - add a new functionality to the theme along with its UI

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am new in wordpress world and i am planning to do a small store website, all the functionalities i need are already there in woocommerce, but there is this small functionality i need which is as below:

- in the homepage i need to show 3 different services are served from the company and each service will have a button which will show a popup or redirect the user to another page.
- the popup or the new page will ask the user to enter his information along with his mobile number so the company could contact him.

and i have chooses this theme https://themebeez.com/demos/?theme=orchid-store

and here is a picture of where exactly the change will be

[image]

So my question is what is the fastest way to do that, is there a plugin to do this for me, or i should make the actual functionality myself and edit the theme code also manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Please go read How to Ask. We expect you to ask specific questions here, about problems with code you have written. We are not here to help you find different plugins or anything like that. If you want to get help here - then you need to describe to us what you have already tried to solve the problem yourself. If your questions are those, I would responde "I don't know, have you tried searching it?" and "Yes, coding it will help you to have more control over that"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the homepage i need to show 3 different services are served from
> the company and each service will have a button which will show a
> popup or redirect the user to another page.

Basically 3 buttons that got you to another page. That can be easily done with just editing the template. Look the support documentation to see if your theme can be edited by some page builder (mine uses Composer, etc) and just add the "buttons", if not you need to edit the template manually with some HTML. Nothing to complicated, it just HTML, not PHP or JS.

> the popup or the new page will ask the user to enter his information
> along with his mobile number so the company could contact him.
> Blockquote

Please clarify, popup or a new page? If it is a new page, when you create the 3 buttons on the homepage, just connect that to a new page each (in the Admin Panel, New>>Page). That it is easy as just but the `<a href>` tag. But also, that's just how I would do it in a short time.

> So my question is what is the fastest way to do that, is there a
> plugin to do this for me, or i should make the actual functionality
> myself and edit the theme code also manually?

Where is going to go that data? In the database? or is going to be sent to some admin email?

But I think there is exist a lots of plugins to help you with that. You just need some custom fields so [Have you tried searching for some? I use one to get in contact with clients which may fulfill your requirements](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Contact%20Form)